# How can I run a perl script in a jenkins pipeline step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configued a pipeline script in jenkins . In one stage , I need to run a perl script with arguments ,like :

```
pipeline{

 agent any

    stages {

     stage('First Stage')
        {
            steps
            {
                 dir ("path_to_script")

                 sh "#!/usr/bin/perl -w test.pl --arg ar1 --arg ar2 --arg ar3"
            }

        }
```

This code is not helping me. How can I execute the script test.pl ?

Answer (score 2):

It feels a bit odd to me that you're supplying everything to the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Essentially, you're saying that the interpreter for the remainder of the file is perl with the full set of arguments (which then gets no code to execute supplied). Why I can imagine that this still works, I'd recommend to just call perl:

```
sh "/usr/bin/perl -w test.pl --arg ar1 --arg ar2 --arg ar3"
```

and not bring in the shebang definition.

This would only make sense to me, if you would supply a perl script (and then also _Michael J_s' answer would make sense to me because of the multi-line quotes:

```
sh """#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello, World!\n";"""
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is a couple years old now, but just for the record...

```
steps
{
    dir ("path_to_script")

    sh "#!/usr/bin/perl -w test.pl --arg ar1 --arg ar2 --arg ar3"
}
```

Unlike cd, dir is not a command that takes effect and persists. Rather, in keeping with the declarative pipeline, it's a block, for example:

```
dir ("path_to_script") {
    sh "/usr/bin/perl -w ./test.pl --arg ar1"
}
```

I believe the shebang from the documentation was for if the script was inline.  For that matter, if test.pl has the shebang as its first line (#!/usr/bin/perl -w), then this reduces to:

```
dir ("path_to_script") {
    sh "./test.pl --arg ar1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the quotes around your call to perl with three single quotes.  This worked for me:

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages 
    {
        stage('First Stage')
        { 
            steps
            {
                sh '''#!/usr/bin/perl -v'''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really wondering, why this should make it any better.. triple quotes are for multi-string, which you aren't even using.

Comment: @StephenKing correct! I only offered this a quick example to show the triple quotes approach vs the single quotes in the original post.  Your answer is more complete, showing the subtlety of calling Perl directly in single quotes vs using the shebang in triple quotes.